# Keeping the drop down menu top item highlighted while scrolling

Tags: html, css

How do I go about keeping the menu item at the top (eg. file) remain highlighted while I am browsing though menu options in the sub menu?

Here's a paste bin: http://pastebin.com/aGJh8nQa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why, with this selector, of course!

```
#menu li:hover > a {
 background-color: rgb(216,216,216);
}
```

[**View it on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/A7qU3/)